# How to achieve stacking in CSS grid layout

Tags: css, grid-layout

I would like some help from the CSS Gurus please.
I need to make a Grid Layout whereby there are 3 divs within the grid. the first div takes up 2 thirds of the width and is twice the height of the other 2. The other 2 divs need to take up 1 third each and should therefore stack on top of each other in the remaining third.

Please assist?

Comment: There are CSS grid generator tools out there that can be a great place to mock up a layout while you're learning. I would use one of those and modify it until you are happy with the result and understand how it's being achieved.

Comment: Please read [ask], then [edit] with a [mcve] of your specific issue. *"Do this for me"* is not in the expected format Q&A format for this site. Show your best effort in resolving your issue. There are so many resources and examples on how to use Grid both here on StackOverflow and on the WWW.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So the snippet should work for you.

```css
body { margin: 0 } body > * { height: 100vh }

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
  "lg lg sm1"
  "lg lg sm2"
}

.grid > div { border: 1px solid grey }

.lg { grid-area: lg }
.sm1 { grid-area: sm1 }
.sm2 { grid-area: sm2 }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="lg">Large</div>
  <div class="sm1">Small 1</div>
  <div class="sm2">Small 2</div>
</div>
```

Otherwise hop onto a grid layout builder and see how you get on. I've set up an example for you https://grid.layoutit.com/?id=TtnKCtI